# Rails upgrade is complaining about older bundler version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade, bundler, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to upgrade from Rails 4.2 to 6.  I have updated my Gemfile to include

```
fail "run 'gem install bundler' to update your bundler version" unless Bundler::VERSION >= '2.0.0'
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '~> 2.7.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
```

But attempting to upgrade the rails gem results in

```
$ bundle update rails
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
    3: from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    2: from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:294:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:275:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (1.17.3) required by your /Users/myusername/myrailsapp/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:1.17.3`

When I try and update the bundler, I get

$ bundle update --bundler
Fetching https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
You have requested:
  rails ~> 6.0.0

The bundle currently has rails locked at 4.2.10.
Try running `bundle update rails`

If you are updating multiple gems in your Gemfile at once,
try passing them all to `bundle update`
```

And as you might expect, running “bundle update” also results in an error …

```
$ bundle update
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
    3: from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    2: from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:294:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:275:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (1.17.3) required by your /Users/myusername/myrailsapp/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:1.17.3`
```

Not sure where else to go from here.

Comment: have you tried `gem install bundler:1.17.3`?

Comment: Leaving aside the bundler version, you should try an incremental upgrade: 5, 5.1, 5.2 then 6.  There are a lot of changes between 4 and 6, a lot.